# NullPointerException on BroadCastReceiver class;

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, crash

My app contains a list of locals and each local has a date. When I click a local, I open a new activity with the local information and I create an alarm based on this date. The alarm should wake up 2 days before the date provided in this local. This is how I'm doing it:

**When I enter the local Activity:**

```
private void scheduleAlarm(Date notificationDate) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Receiver.class).putExtra("myString", myString);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC, notificationDate.getTime(), pendingIntent);
}
```

**Receiver Class:**

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String myString = intent.getStringExtra("myString");
        if (myString.matches("myString") Toast.makeText(context, "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Registering in the manifest:**

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver" android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This normally works fine, but when I reboot the phone, as soon I enter the main screen I get a crash on my app.

I implemented fabric crashlytics on my app and if I check for the crash I get a NullPointerException: pattern == null on my Receiver.class.

My bet is that when I reboot my phone I lose the extras of the intent and this line is getting a NullPointerException:

```
String myString = intent.getStringExtra("myString");
```

Has anyone got any clue? How should I aproach this crash?

Comment: If I check if myString is null or matches " ", and only proceed otherwise, I don't get the crash, so I am getting this crash indeed because the extras are null when I reboot the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a general rule, do `"myString".matches(myString)` and you won't have to do two checks.

The reason the intent doesn't have extras is because you're not receiving an alarm event, but rather the `BOOT_COMPLETED` event, which doesn't have any extras. At boot completion, you will need to reschedule your alarms, extras and all, as `AlarmManager` does not persist through reboot.